# IDFA in iOS App, instead of UDID

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, udid, idfa

I'm currently using IDFA instead of UUID in my iOS App for identifying devices uniquely. But doesn't have any advertisement in the App. Would App store accept the App, if so which of the option below is to be chosen ?

[image: Submission Page]

Comment: IDFA is used even for facebook sharing. I don't thinK your app will be rejected for not having advertisement while setting IDFA "YES"

Comment: Thanks, in that case which option should I be choosing?

Comment: mark 2nd option ,installation one , you will receive invalid binary error via email if apple has any rejection . Or Use contact us option and describe your usage for IDFA .

Comment: You should probably use `identifierForVendor` rather than IDFA

Comment: My app was rejected for using `IDFA` without advertisement, the only right way now is using `identifierForVendor`. If you need this ID to persist after reinstallation, just save it into keychain. Keychain items stay alive even after app uninstall.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `identifierForVendor` for this.

Refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor)

Its straight forward & easy to use. Let me know if you need anymore clarification.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using IDFA and don't serve advertisements then your app could be rejected.**

When submitting your app for review, you’ll be asked whether your app uses the Advertising Identifier (IDFA) to serve advertisements. If you indicate that your app uses the IDFA, but it **does not have ad functionality or does not display ads properly, your app may be rejected.** Make sure to test your app on an iOS device to verify that ads work correctly. Similarly, if you indicate that your app does not use the IDFA, but it does, your app will be put into the “Invalid Binary” status.

Check this: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=08282014a